# File Upload fails during recording

Tags: asp.net, jmeter

I have one ASP.Net application, it has upload functionality.
On click of Upload a windows application get installed/opened and it has upload feature.

When i run normally it works fine but when i set proxy on browser for Jmeter application recording works fine but as soon as i click on this Upload Utility(Windows application) it gives me error as "Application download did not succeed, Check your network connection  or contact the administrator".

I am using Jmeter and trying to record the upload scenario.

How this can be resolved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build it manually. Create a post Request and ensure the following

1. Copy uploading file to JMeter's "bin" folder
   [image]
2. Don't forget to tick Use multipart/form-data for HTTP POST box
3. Make sure you provide correct Parameter name and MIME Type
4. Provide parameters.(if any)

Comment: Accepting your answer as second issue was resolved with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with Jmeter certificate. After installing the certificate also it was giving me same error after i added certficate as trusted on my computer it worked.
After this also i faced issue while uploading and in order to resolve this i followed below thing..

Copy uploading file to JMeter's "bin" folder